# How can I create a login page using Ionic 2 framework that then leads to a tabbed view?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Currenty, in my `app.html`file, I have:

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab1" tabIcon="time"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab2" tabIcon="paper"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Tab3" tabIcon="more"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

and in my `app.js` file, after doing the proper imports of these pages, I have:

```
    this.tab1Root = Page1;
    this.tab2Root = Page2;
    this.tab3Root = Page3;
```

I want the application to open with a login page, and then from there progress to this tabbed view. I'm not sure how to logically set this up in the context of `app.html` and `app.js`

**I'm only interested in answers involving Ionic 2 (and Angular 2+), not the older versions.**

Answer (score 5):

In your app, define this:

```
export class YourApp {
  rootPage: Type = LoginPage;

  constructor(app: IonicApp, platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

    });
  }
}
```

In your LoginPage, it should have this:

```
export class LoginPage {
    constructor(nav: NavController) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    doLogin() {
        if (loginSuccessful) {
           this.nav.setRoot(YourTabsPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if your app is always opening with login page, you should:

1- Put your login page in app.html

2- Import and inject [NavController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/) in your app.js constructor.

```
import {NavController} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';

constructor(nav: NavController) {
    this.nav = nav;
}
```

3- Create a new Tabs parent component. ( your current app.js ) and call it TabsParentComponent for example.

4- In app.js, once the login is successful, call:

```
this.nav.setRoot(TabsParentComponent)
```